# Getting Error Code 405 when uploading files using ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, gulp, ng-file-upload

I am trying to implement a file upload functionality using ng-file-upload based on an example found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/).

Everything seems to be working fine except that when I try to upload the file to my local webserver, I get an `Error Code 405 (Method not allowed)`.

Here is a part of my markup:

```
<div class="block form-group">
        <label for="photo">Photos:</label>
        <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="addCourtCtrl.picFile" name="file"
               accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required
               ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
        <img ng-show="addRegisterForm.file.$valid" ngf-thumbnail="picFile" class="thumb"> 
        <button ng-click="addCourtCtrl.picFile = null" ng-show="addCourtCtrl.picFile">Remove</button>
        <br>
        <button ng-click="addCourtCtrl.uploadPic(addCourtCtrl.picFile)">
            Upload
        </button>
        <span class="progress" ng-show="addCourtCtrl.picFile.progress >= 0">
            <div style="width:{{addCourtCtrl.picFile.progress}}%"
                 ng-bind="addCourtCtrl.picFile.progress + '%'"></div>
        </span>
        <span ng-show="picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
        <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
    </div>
```

and here's the definition of my upload function:

```
this.uploadPic = function (file) {
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
            url: '/www/images/uploads/courts',
            data: { username: __this.username, file: file },
        });

        file.upload.then(function (response) {
            $timeout(function () {
                file.result = response.data;
            });
        }, function (response) {
            alert('Upload Failed');
            if (response.status > 0)
                __this.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function (evt) {
            // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
            file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });
    }
```

I am using gulp's webserver to run this application and the error doesn't show when I use the same upload url from the example.

I have been looking at some questions related to this issue but I am new to Angular and I find most of the answers a bit too complicated.

I wish someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably facing the CORS issue. Ajax requests from browser are rejected if performed from different domain. You need to add CORS headers to your backend. Please, take a look here to learn more about CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you give me an idea on how I can do that in my case or point me to an article that explains it?

Comment: @Rian What backend are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any for now. But I plan to use ASP.Net. For now I am testing using hard-coded data.

Comment: @Rian Then how do you handle file upload?

Comment: I am trying to do it directly from inside my controller using the ng-file-upload module.

Comment: @Rian You need something to handle file upload on "'/www/images/uploads/courts'". If you just want to test the usage of ng-file-upload, then the best way is to write some unit tests using `$httpBackend` to mock backend's response. If you want to create real application - you need some backend code to handle the upload. AngularJS controller isn't enough. AngualrJS is not a server framework, as everything happens on the client side.

Comment: I see. I will definitely take a look at `$httpBackend` but I can't do it now. I will get back to this soon. Will let you know of updates. Thanks a lot for your help.